# Binding Linq Query to Entity Class

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am  using a simple LINQ query `SingleOrDefault` in the applicaiton to get  a record and bind it back to entity class. I am getting a exception which says specific cast is not valid.

I ran the SQL Profiler to see  if the query yields successfull result and I was able to row back from database.

Unfortunately the exisitng table has more than 120 columns and I am not able to figure where the casting is getting failed.

Taking a glance on the data would not say me much about where the specific cast is invalid.

Please let me know how to solve this problem or identity exactly which column has invalid cast.

```
PatientDetail objPatientDetails_Toupdate = null;
        objSummitHealthDataContext = new SummitHealthDataContext();
        try
        {
            objPatientDetails_Toupdate = objSummitHealthDataContext.PatientDetails.SingleOrDefault(pd => pd.PatientID == objPatientDetails.PatientID);
            if (objPatientDetails_Toupdate == null)
            {
```

Exception From Stack Trace:

> at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query,
>   QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object
>   lastResult)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query,
>   QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)    at
>   System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source,
>   Expression`1 predicate)    at
>   SummitHealth.CRM.Data.Patient.PatientDAO.SavePatient(PatientDetail
>   objPatientDetails)

Comment: Could you show us your cast?, without code we can't help much

Comment: We need to see your code..!!!

Comment: Sorry tryng to edit and its messing up.Please give me a moment

Comment: I posted the above Rodolfo and Kosala W...Thank You

Comment: So you get an exception in this line ` objPatientDetails_Toupdate = objSummitHealthDataContext.PatientDetails.SingleOrDefault(pd => pd.PatientID == objPatientDetails.PatientID);` ?

Comment: Thats Correct ...I hit the exception there

Comment: Replace `SingleOrDefault` with `FirstOrDefault`. That should work for you.

Comment: I am still getting the same exception with below stach trace :

Comment: Instead of looking into each of the 120 columns just check how you are casting each db type to a c# type. This would narrow down the area at which you'd need to look